# How to use ssh private key for RPC authentication?

Tags: go, ssh, grpc, rpc

Assume we have an RPC server, and admin users have SSH access to the RPC server.

- The RPC server can read `.ssh/authenticated_keys` on the server
- The RPC client reads `.ssh/id_rsa` from client machine

The question is: can the corresponding RPC client use the admin users' local private key for the authentication of the RPC server requests? How?

Comment: typically no because those two clients are executed as different users and filesystem permissions block ability for one to access the other's keys ...  take a look at file permissions for ~someuser/.ssh/somekey    where somekey is the private and somekey.pub is public ...  each ssh key has two files one public which anyone can see and the other private which is never shown to anyone

Comment: Yes. Make the client sign some message with the private key. Make the server verify the signature using the client's public key. The [golang.org/x/crypto/ssh package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) has everything you need to [compute](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Signer) and [verify](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#PublicKey) signatures.